# Non-admin backend user can't reset users passwords

Tags: magento-1.9, admin

Hi I am having n issue where users in the admin panel that don't have full admin privileges cannot reset frontend users passwords.

It asks for the "Admin Password" to reset them and ideally I would like "Moderators" to be able to do this.

Has anyone seen a workaround on this I had a Google and came up with nothing!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

System > Konfiguration > Customers > Customer Configuration > Password option.

Set last Option "Admin user for password change required to "no"